# MYSQL - Need to select substring from request which is not stored in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a request to a database which contains array of strings. Some of these strings are stored in the database, some of them are not. How to get strings from the request which are not stored in the database?

E.g. 
Request: CALL test.friends("111, 222");
Table "user" has a "fields" column. Values ("111, 333") are stored in this column. How to get "222" from the request?

I can write a request for getting data which is in the table but absent in the request:

```
PROCEDURE test.friends(IN phoneArray longtext)
BEGIN
  SET @query1 = CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username) into @phones FROM user WHERE phones NOT IN (', phoneArray, ')');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Could you please write request without creating additional table to save phoneArray?